# How to access members of an inherited object from a base

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am sorry for the unclear title, I wasn't really sure how to word it.
I have an interface; lets call it `Iinterface`;

```
public interface Iinterface
{
    //Some members
}
```

I also have an abstract class that inherits from `Iinterface`; lets call this one `Aabstract`, and this one has a method called `dosomething()`.

```
public abstract class Aabstract : Iinterface
{
    public void dosomething()
    {

    }
}
```

I have a `List<Iinterface>` called `listofIinterfaces` in a part of my code in which each Iinterface may or may not be an `Aabstract`
How might I do something like the following (but working)

```
foreach (Iinterface a in listofIinterfaces)
{
    if (a is Aabstract)
    {
        a.dosomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's problem with this code? Doesn't it work as expected? Do you have other classes also which implement the interface or inherit the abstract class?

Comment: No, it doesn't, I just (re) tried it

Comment: You're testing that a is Aabstract but then trying to call dosomething on an object of type Iinterface. You need to cast `a` or use `as` to get an Aabstract to call dosomething on..

Comment: How were you able to create an object of Abstract class and insert it in the list. One thing you need to understand is you can not create object of an abstract class so in the list you don't have an object of Abstract class that's why it will never go inside the if block. And are you sure `dosomething` method is not part of the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use `as` to attempt to cast the appropriate type:

```
namespace Sample {
    public interface IThing {

    }

    public class Type1 : IThing {
        public void Foo() { }
    }

    public class Type2 : IThing {
        public void Bar() { }
    }

    public class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var list = new List<IThing> {
                new Type1(),
                new Type2()
            };

            foreach (var item in list) {
                var t1 = item as Type1;
                if (t1 != null) {
                    t1.Foo();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using C# 7.0 you can also switch on type, the example is taken from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/):

```
switch(shape)
{
    case Circle c:
        WriteLine($"circle with radius {c.Radius}");
        break;
    case Rectangle s when (s.Length == s.Height):
        WriteLine($"{s.Length} x {s.Height} square");
        break;
    case Rectangle r:
        WriteLine($"{r.Length} x {r.Height} rectangle");
        break;
    default:
        WriteLine("<unknown shape>");
        break;
    case null:
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(shape));
}
```

Comment: Oh! That is cool, I didn't know that `switch` had that feature!